# replace values of a dataframe based on values of the previous rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Supposing I have the data frame below:

```
key         values
A           118    
B           118
B           118
C           100
A            90
A            90
A            90
```

I want to replace the values that have the same key of the previous row with 0.
Then, the data would be like:

```
key         values
A           118    
B           118
B             0
C           100
A            90
A             0
A             0
```

For a data frame called 'm', I used for and if:

```
for (i in 1:(length(m[,1])-1)) {

   if (m[,1][i+1]==m[,1][i]) {m[,2][i+1]<- 0}

 }
```

It works, but my data has 2104776 rows and 23 columns. So, it took 3 hours.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this task. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `lag` from `dplyr` and check if the value in `key` is same as its previous value and assign 0 to those who match.

```
library(dplyr)
df$values[df$key == lag(df$key)] <- 0

df
#  key  value
#1   A  118
#2   B  118
#3   B    0
#4   C  100
#5   A   90
#6   A    0
#7   A    0
```

Comment: It could also be `df$values[with(df, head(key, -1) == tail(key, -1))] <- 0`

Comment: the lag() function is very usuful. Did the task quickly! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In `data.table` you could use `rleid` to group, like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, values := c(head(values, 1), rep(0L, .N-1)), by=rleid(key)]
df
   key values
1:   A    118
2:   B    118
3:   B      0
4:   C    100
5:   A     90
6:   A      0
7:   A      0
```

`c(head(values, 1), rep(0L, .N-1))` takes the first element of values and prepends this to a vector of 0s the length of the groups minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

You basically take cusmsum of the keys cols and then subtract an index of length of those key to give you a vector which should hold the values and you can convert everything else to 0.

```
i=cumsum(rle(as.character(df$key))$lengths)-(rle(as.character(df$key))$lengths-1)
df$values[-i]=0
```